# FTP connection between two Windows Machines

Tags: windows, ftp, ports

I have two Windows machines, both are running Windows 8 Release Preview. One of them is connected to a network via the ethernet cable, the other is connected to the network via wifi.

IP address of machine 1 is : 192.168.1.2
IP address of machine 2 is : 192.168.1.4

I have also added a rule in the windows firewall to allow ftp.exe to access all ports for all incoming and outgoing connections, on both the machines.

I am unable to connect to either of the machines via ftp. The FTP request keeps on timing out. Is there anything that I am not doing right, or haven't done at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming that you already had the client - server installed you could check in your routers configuration if the ftp port that you need it's open and pointing to the right url, in this case the FTP server IP

Also there is the chance that your active/passive connection are not properly configured.

Here you'll find some general information: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Answer (score 0):

You should install an FTP server on one or both machines.

You are using the Windows FTP client but it cannot talk to another FTP client

Here a [free FTP Server](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server)